# ValueError: ('%s is not decorated with @add_arg_scope', ('__main__', 'bottleneck'))

Tags: python, tensorflow

Here is the code

```
with tf.variable_scope(scope, 'resnet_v2', [inputs], reuse=reuse) as sc:
    end_points_collection = sc.original_name_scope + '_end_points'
    with slim.arg_scope([slim.conv2d, bottleneck, stack_blocks_dense],
                        outputs_collections=[end_points_collection]):
```

> ValueError: ('%s is not decorated with @add_arg_scope', ('**main**', 'bottleneck'))
>   d:\resnet\main_resnet.py(219)resnet_v2() 
>   -> outputs_collections=[end_points_collection])

So what is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

forgive my stupid question, just decorates the function with @add_arg_scope before the definition of bottleneck

```
@add_arg_scope
def bottleneck():
```