# Tensorflow - Train.py - ValueError: ('%s is not decorated with @add_arg_scope', ('nets.mobilenet.mobilenet', 'depth_multiplier'))

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to make a custom object-detection model following this tutorial: https://towardsdatascience.com/custom-object-detection-using-tensorflow-from-scratch-e61da2e10087

Everything worked fine until the Step 10, where I have to train my model using the train.py script (with tensorflow 1).

When I run the script (macOS) :

```
python3 train.py     --alsologtostderr     --train_dir=train     --pipeline_config_path=/Users/sol.arabehety/Desktop/models-master/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.config
```

I get this error:

```
File "/Users/sol.arabehety/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/arg_scope.py", line 152, in arg_scope
    _name_op(op))
ValueError: ('%s is not decorated with @add_arg_scope', ('nets.mobilenet.mobilenet', 'depth_multiplier'))
```

I found this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/53038290/1269404 but I don't know where I have to add the **@add_arg_scope** tag, can you help me?

This is the arg_scope.py file:
https://github.com/google-research/tf-slim/blob/master/tf_slim/ops/arg_scope.py  (line 152)

This is the complete error:

```
models-master$ sudo python3 train.py     --alsologtostderr     --train_dir=train     --pipeline_config_path=/Users/sol.arabehety/Desktop/models-master/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.config
/Users/sol.arabehety/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:526: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
/Users/sol.arabehety/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:527: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
/Users/sol.arabehety/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:528: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
/Users/sol.arabehety/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:529: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
/Users/sol.arabehety/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:530: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
/Users/sol.arabehety/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:535: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])

WARNING: The TensorFlow contrib module will not be included in TensorFlow 2.0.
For more information, please see:
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/addons
If you depend on functionality not listed there, please file an issue.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/sol.arabehety/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py:125: main (from __main__) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use object_detection/model_main.py.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/sol.arabehety/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/object_detection/legacy/trainer.py:266: create_global_step (from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.train.create_global_step
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/sol.arabehety/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py:263: colocate_with (from tensorflow.python.framework.ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Colocations handled automatically by placer.
WARNING:tensorflow:num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/sol.arabehety/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/object_detection/core/preprocessor.py:188: sample_distorted_bounding_box (from tensorflow.python.ops.image_ops_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
`seed2` arg is deprecated.Use sample_distorted_bounding_box_v2 instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/sol.arabehety/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/object_detection/core/batcher.py:96: batch (from tensorflow.python.training.input) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Queue-based input pipelines have been replaced by `tf.data`. Use `tf.data.Dataset.batch(batch_size)` (or `padded_batch(...)` if `dynamic_pad=True`).
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/sol.arabehety/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py:753: QueueRunner.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.training.queue_runner_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
To construct input pipelines, use the `tf.data` module.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/sol.arabehety/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py:753: add_queue_runner (from tensorflow.python.training.queue_runner_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
To construct input pipelines, use the `tf.data` module.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/sol.arabehety/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py:784: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.cast instead.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 186, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/Users/sol.arabehety/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/Users/sol.arabehety/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 324, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "train.py", line 182, in main
    graph_hook_fn=graph_rewriter_fn)
  File "/Users/sol.arabehety/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/object_detection/legacy/trainer.py", line 291, in train
    clones = model_deploy.create_clones(deploy_config, model_fn, [input_queue])
  File "/Users/sol.arabehety/Desktop/models-master/research/slim/deployment/model_deploy.py", line 192, in create_clones
    outputs = model_fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sol.arabehety/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/object_detection/legacy/trainer.py", line 204, in _create_losses
    prediction_dict = detection_model.predict(images, true_image_shapes)
  File "/Users/sol.arabehety/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/object_detection/meta_architectures/ssd_meta_arch.py", line 568, in predict
    preprocessed_inputs)
  File "/Users/sol.arabehety/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/object_detection/models/ssd_mobilenet_v2_feature_extractor.py", line 118, in extract_features
    [mobilenet.depth_multiplier], min_depth=self._min_depth):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/Users/sol.arabehety/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/arg_scope.py", line 152, in arg_scope
    _name_op(op))
ValueError: ('%s is not decorated with @add_arg_scope', ('nets.mobilenet.mobilenet', 'depth_multiplier'))
```

Comment: So... is there a file   File "/Users/sol.arabehety/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/arg_scope.py" ?? Do you see line 152?

Comment: I updated the post with the arg_scope.py file, I don't know where I have to put the tag (and if that is the right solution)

Comment: Your  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53038290/1269404) shows the problem. There the programmer had to find bottleneck function at main. So in your case you have to find depth_multiplier at nets.mobilenet.mobilenet. IF the last one is something that is downloaded during selection of backbone for the model then you are at a dead end. Sorry but you have to train with Tensorflow v2. and better to follow instructions at Tensorflow github. I am happy to help if you have.... a dataset.

Comment: If I wanted to train I would follow [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection). It is the safest solution with examples. Inside you can find how to [bring](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) your own dataset....which is the hardest part as it takes time to prepare it right!

Comment: Oh that explains why I couldn't find the depth_multiplier definition... I see I'm in the dead end. I tried with Tensorflow2 but I had problems with the Slim/ contrib library... anyway, I'll try again following the tutorial you gave me. Thanks! Please let the answer below so I can mark it as correct :)

Comment: Thanks :) I am really interested in this. If you stuck tag me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53038290/1269404) shows the problem. There the programmer had to find bottleneck function at main. So in your case you have to find depth_multiplier at nets.mobilenet.mobilenet. IF the last one is something that is downloaded during selection of backbone for the model then you are at a dead end. Sorry but you have to train with Tensorflow v2. and better to follow instructions at Tensorflow github. I am happy to help if you have.... a dataset.

If I wanted to train I would follow [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection). It is the safest solution with examples. Inside you can find how to [bring](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) your own dataset....which is the hardest part as it takes time to prepare it right!

Answer (score 0):

So I had the exact same issue I believe. The only way that worked to fix it was by actually commenting out the check for the add_arg_scope. In my case I had to go find E:\anaconda3\envs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\contrib\framework\python\ops\arg_scope.py and started going through steps.